# Claim about the z-transform of a discrete function

Tags: complex-analysis, z-transform

Claim:

> $\lim_{k\to\infty} x[k]$  exist and if finite is $X(z)$ the Z-transform
>   of $x[k]$ has no pole in $|z|>1$ and at most  1 pole at $z = 1$

Attempt:
\begin{align*}
   X(z) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k]z^{-k}\\\
   H(z)/G(z) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k]z^{-k}\\\
\end{align*}

First prove that no pole can be in $|z|>1$
\begin{align*}
   H(z)/G(z) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k]z^{-k}\\\
   H(z)/[(z-a)G'(z)] &=  \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k]z^{-k},  a>1\\\
   H(z)/[(z-a)G'(z)] &= x[0] + x[1]z^{-1} +x[2]z^{-2}+x[3]z^{-3}...\\\
   H(z)/G'(z)     &= (z-a)(x[0] + x[1]z^{-1} +x[2]z^{-2}+x[3]z^{-3}...)\\\
\end{align*}

Can someone help carry this further?